# How to make Oracle EXTRACT(HOUR FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) function return the actual hour (it returns one hour behind)

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, timezone, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm creating a trigger that must check if an action is taken inside an hour range in the day, say between 9 and 18(6pm).

The problem I am facing is when I use the Oracle `EXTRACT()` function it return a number which is 1 hour behind from actual hour.

Example,

```
select current_timestamp from dual;
```

gives me **22.09.01 12:49:23,733000000 EUROPE/LISBON** as a result, but when I run:

```
select extract(HOUR FROM current_timestamp) from dual;
```

I get **11** as a result, although it should be **12**. I believe that this is due to daylight saving but I cannot solve it. I already tried to run:

```
ALTER SESSION SET TIME_ZONE='Europe/Lisbon';
```

but the problem remains. How can I retrieve the correct hour for my timezone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `TO_CHAR` do?

This is what you have (actually, what *I* have):

```
SQL> select current_timestamp from dual;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
01-SEP-22 02.03.51.592000 PM +02:00

SQL> select extract(hour from current_timestamp) from dual;

EXTRACT(HOURFROMCURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
----------------------------------
                                12
```

The `TO_CHAR` option:

```
SQL> select to_char(current_timestamp, 'hh24') from dual;

TO
--
14

SQL>
```

Comment: Yes, TO_CHAR does the job perfectly. Thankyou @Littlefoot

Answer (score 1):

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/EXTRACT-datetime.html#GUID-36E52BF8-945D-437D-9A3C-6860CABD210E):

> When extracting from a datetime with a time zone value, the value returned is in UTC.

You can explicitly cast to a plain timestamp first to avoid that by discarding the time zone information:

```
select extract(HOUR FROM cast(current_timestamp as timestamp)) from dual;
```

You can see the difference with:

```
select current_timestamp,
  extract(HOUR FROM current_timestamp) as utc,
  extract(HOUR FROM cast(current_timestamp as timestamp)) as result
from dual;

CURRENT_TIMESTAMP                          UTC RESULT
--------------------------------------- ------ ------
01-SEP-22 14.11.54.505920 EUROPE/LISBON     13     14
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=dd7139564989357a46bf9ef66be8d9d5)

---

> check if an action is taken inside an hour range in the day

If you base this check on `current_timestamp` then a user would potentially be able to work around it by changing their session time zone, to make it appear that 'now' is in the allowed window, whatever the time really is. If you use `systimestamp` instead then they wouldn't be able to do that. (You may need to adjust the window if the system is in a different time zone - check if `systimestamp` is reporting your local Lisbon time.)

Answer (score 0):

I have to deal with this from time to time working for a global company.

Like you mentioned check your timestamp.

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM DUAL;
```

Then try to put you region in this function to determine the delta

```
SELECT TZ_OFFSET('Europe/London') FROM DUAL;  --Put your region here
```

This could be used to force an extra hour if you already know the difference.

```
select extract(HOUR FROM current_timestamp + INTERVAL '1' HOUR) FROM DUAL;
```

You could also try to use the FROM_TZ (Timezone) function to add or subtract time from your date/time.

```
SELECT FROM_TZ(TIMESTAMP '2022-09-01 12:44:00', '+01:00') FROM DUAL;
```